# Spaces between rows and cols in a table - Better ways than mine?

Tags: tables, spacing

I started using Latex recently and I put together 4 ways of changing the space in a table. Two general ways defining the general space between cols and rows as well as two ways of adding space between certain rows or cols. I was wondering if the 4 ways I use are the best or most common one to use to adjust space in a table?

Here is my simple example:

```
\begin{table}

    \setlength{\tabcolsep}{6pt} % General space between cols (6pt standard)
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1} % General space between rows (1 standard)
    % Add @{\hskip Xpt} to tabular to add space between certain columns
    % Add [Xpt] after \\ of a certain row to add extra space before next row

    \begin{tabular}{c@{\hskip 12pt}c}

        % table content

    \end{tabular}

\end{table}
```

Answer (score 23):

I normally use changing `tabcolsep` and `arraystretch`, as you showed in the question:

```
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{6pt} % General space between cols (6pt standard)
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1} % General space between rows (1 standard)
```

I've had bad experiences with `[Xpt]` in very complex tables (multirows and multicols), and the syntax `@{\hskip Xpt}`... first time I see this!

Hope this helped!

Answer (score 13):

Your described ways are correct. In the next steps I will quote the [manual of array](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/array) and the [documentation of LaTeX2e source2e](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/source2e):

[*array*](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/array)

> `@{decl.}`
>
> Suppresses inter-column space and inserts decl. instead.

[*source2e:*](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/source2e)

> **ARRAY PARMETERS:**
>
> `\arraycolsep`
>
> : half the width separating columns in an array environment
>
> `\tabcolsep`
>
> : half the width separating columns in a tabular environment
>
> `\arraystretch`
>
> : line spacing in array and tabular environments is done by placing a strut
>   in every row of height and depth `\arraystretch` times the height and
>   depth of the strut produced by an ordinary `\strut` commmand.
>
> `\extracolsep{WIDTH}`
>
> : for use inside an @ in the preamble. Causes a WIDTH space to be added  between columns for the rest of the columns. This is in addition to the ordinary
>   intercolumn space.

combination of [*array*](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/array) and [*source2e*](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/source2e)

> In the macro `\@array` the line separator `\\` is \let to the command
>   `\@arraycr`.
>
> ```
> \@argarraycr[LENGTH]
> ```

Comment: Special interest in `\extracolsep{WIDTH}`, here which doesn't appear in many of the other answers around the site and lets you force tables-within-tables together.

Comment: this is a really important answer! The difference between \tabcolsep and \arraycolsep is important! \arraystretch will work on either arrays or tables, but \tabcolsep doesn't work on arrays, so one must use \arraycolsep. This is what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

I always use `tabcolsep` and `arraystretch` for modifying spaces between rows and columns in a table. This works fine, even for complex table structures.

```
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{6pt}     % General space between columns (6pt standard)
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1} % General space between rows (1 standard)
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SE! This just seems to repeat information provided in the question. Could you explain how this constitutes an answer?

Comment: Hi, probably you haven't noticed that the question asked whether the specified ways are the best or commonly used ones. That's why I replied to let people know that yes these are the common ones but don't know about whether they are the best ones. Cheers !

Comment: Well, 'I always use...' doesn't really show 'commonly used'. On the other hand, what would? A survey of TeX users? (And so what?) So that bit of the question may not really be answerable. But what does this add to the other answers?