# How to align a system of multiline equations?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, equations, arrays, multline

I've got a system of equations, each of them doesn't fit the page width, so I'm searching the way to align them so that:

- the brace should appear to the left with no indentation
- the first line of each equation should be left-aligned
- the last line of each equation should be right-aligned

I reached the following:
[image]
but I don't like the huge spacing between the brace and the 1-st letter of each equation.

The code I used is the following:

```
\[
\setlength{\multlinegap}{0pt}
\left\{
\begin{array}{c}
\shoveleft{A_{PP}\sin\alpha_{P1} - A_{PS}\cos\alpha_{S1} +B_{PP} \sin\alpha_{P2} +B_{PS} \cos\alpha_{S2} =} \\ \shoveright{=\sin\alpha_{P1},} \\
% 2-nd equation
\shoveleft{ A_{PP}\cos\alpha_{P1}  +A_{PS} \sin\alpha_{S1} -B_{PP}\cos\alpha_{P2} + B_{PS} \sin\alpha_{S2} = } \\
\shoveright{ =\cos\alpha_{P1},} \\
% 3-rd equation
\shoveleft{ A_{PP}\gamma_{P1} \cos 2\alpha_{S1} +A_{PS}  \gamma_{S1} \sin 2\alpha_{S1} +B_{PP}  \gamma_{P2} \cos 2\alpha_{S2} -} \\
\shoveright{- B_{PS}   \gamma_{S2} \sin 2\alpha_{S2} = \gamma_{P1} \cos 2\alpha_{S1},} \\
% 4-th equation
\shoveleft{ -A_{PP}n_1 \gamma_{S1} \sin 2\alpha_{P1} +A_{PS}  \gamma_{S1} \cos 2\alpha_{S1} +B_{PP} n_2 \gamma_{S2} \sin 2\alpha_{P2} +} \\
\shoveright{+ B_{PS} \gamma_{S2} \cos 2\alpha_{S2} = n_1 \gamma_{S1} \sin 2\alpha_{P1}.}\end{array}
\right.
\]
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You can use `\begin{array}{@{}c@{}}`

Comment: Marco Daniel, that doesn't seem  to help if this line is directly pasted into my code instead of the 4-th line \begin{array}{c}. I observe 2 negative effects: (1) the spacing is still there; (2) the equations do not occupy the full text width, the gap appears to the right, which is undesirable.

Comment: The space is removed I tested it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the `multlined` environment from `mathtools` is your friend.  (it loads `amsmath`, so there's no need to do that).

two things to note about this example:

- `\mathindent` is set to zero width within a group so it will disappear after the display ends.
- since `multlined` (like `multline`) automatically sets the first line flush left and the last line flush right, you don't want the `\shove...` commands on those lines.  in fact, the spacing will be compromised if you *do* wrap those lines in `\shove...` arguments.

here's the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[fleqn]{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\noindent some text here
{\mathindent=0pt
\[
\setlength{\multlinegap}{0pt}
\left\{
\begin{multlined}
A_{PP}\sin\alpha_{P1} - A_{PS}\cos\alpha_{S1} +B_{PP} \sin\alpha_{P2} +B_{PS} \cos\alpha_{S2} = \\
\shoveright{=\sin\alpha_{P1},} \\
% 2-nd equation
\shoveleft{ A_{PP}\cos\alpha_{P1}  +A_{PS} \sin\alpha_{S1} -B_{PP}\cos\alpha_{P2} + B_{PS} \sin\alpha_{S2} = } \\
\shoveright{ =\cos\alpha_{P1},} \\
% 3-rd equation
\shoveleft{ A_{PP}\gamma_{P1} \cos 2\alpha_{S1} +A_{PS}  \gamma_{S1} \sin 2\alpha_{S1} +B_{PP}  \gamma_{P2} \cos 2\alpha_{S2} -} \\
\shoveright{- B_{PS}   \gamma_{S2} \sin 2\alpha_{S2} = \gamma_{P1} \cos 2\alpha_{S1},} \\
% 4-th equation
\shoveleft{ -A_{PP}n_1 \gamma_{S1} \sin 2\alpha_{P1} +A_{PS}  \gamma_{S1} \cos 2\alpha_{S1} +B_{PP} n_2 \gamma_{S2} \sin 2\alpha_{P2} +} \\
+ B_{PS} \gamma_{S2} \cos 2\alpha_{S2} = n_1 \gamma_{S1} \sin 2\alpha_{P1}.
\end{multlined}
\right.
\] }

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @azetina -- thanks for adding the image.  (i didn't have time.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton Sure you are most welcome. I actually like answers and questions with resulting output. So whenever I see one I try to put in the images.

Comment: What are the alternatives to `multilined` where all the lines are left-aligned?

Comment: @Diaa -- I can't think of any alternative that isn't also greatly contrived.  That can't fit in a comment, and this question is too old to want to change the answer.  Please ask a new question, referencing this question and saying why the answer here is unsatisfactory.

Answer (score 4):

This is not directly addressing your question, but more about making the information easier to parse. I would suggest the following changes to make the pattern easier to see:

- Eliminate the double equal signs
- align the terms across multiple lines

[image]

### Notes:

- The leading minus sign on the last equation has non-standard spacing but I think it looks better in this case
- You could also consider aligning the middle `+/-` signs (and perhaps even the equal signs) to make the pattern ever more obvious.

There are many ways to achieve this, so this is just to show one method.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\Phantom}{\phantom{{}+{}}}%
\newcommand{\Plus}{{}+{}}%
\newcommand{\Minus}{{}-{}}%

\begin{document}
\[\begin{cases}
\Phantom A_{PP}\sin\alpha_{P1} - A_{PS}\cos\alpha_{S1} \\
        \Plus B_{PP}\sin\alpha_{P2} + B_{PS}\cos\alpha_{S2} =
         \sin\alpha_{P1}, \\[7pt]
% 2-nd equation
\Phantom A_{PP}\cos\alpha_{P1}  +A_{PS} \sin\alpha_{S1} \\
\Minus B_{PP}\cos\alpha_{P2} + B_{PS} \sin\alpha_{S2} = \cos\alpha_{P1}, \\[7pt]
% 3-rd equation
\Phantom A_{PP}\gamma_{P1} \cos 2\alpha_{S1} +A_{PS}  \gamma_{S1} \sin 2\alpha_{S1} \\
\Plus B_{PP}  \gamma_{P2} \cos 2\alpha_{S2}
- B_{PS}   \gamma_{S2} \sin 2\alpha_{S2} = \gamma_{P1} \cos 2\alpha_{S1}, \\[7pt]
% 4-th equation
\Minus A_{PP}n_1 \gamma_{S1} \sin 2\alpha_{P1} +A_{PS}  \gamma_{S1} \cos 2\alpha_{S1} \\
\Plus B_{PP} n_2 \gamma_{S2} \sin 2\alpha_{P2} +
       B_{PS} \gamma_{S2} \cos 2\alpha_{S2} = n_1 \gamma_{S1} \sin 2\alpha_{P1}.
\end{cases}\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for the comment.

I can't eliminate the double signs because the Russian typographical tradition requires the sign to be repeated if the equation is split at this sign (1st time - at the end of the line; 2nd - in the beginning of the new line).

I agree that the equations are more readable if using your way :), but currently I've got to follow the publisher's requirements (most of them on the alignment are specified in the question)

Answer (score 2):

To remove the space between the row and the brace you can use the declaration `@{}`. The declaration `@{}` is described here:

[Spaces between rows and cols in a table - Better ways than mine?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/56101/spaces-between-rows-and-cols-in-a-table-better-ways-than-mine/58135#58135)

To provide an equation about the whole contents you can use the command `\resizebox`. Note this results in an unwanted size of the equation.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\[
\setlength{\multlinegap}{0pt}
\left\{
\begin{array}{c}
\shoveleft{A_{PP}\sin\alpha_{P1} - A_{PS}\cos\alpha_{S1} +B_{PP} \sin\alpha_{P2} +B_{PS} \cos\alpha_{S2} =} \\ \shoveright{=\sin\alpha_{P1},} \\
% 2-nd equation
\shoveleft{ A_{PP}\cos\alpha_{P1}  +A_{PS} \sin\alpha_{S1} -B_{PP}\cos\alpha_{P2} + B_{PS} \sin\alpha_{S2} = } \\
\shoveright{ =\cos\alpha_{P1},} \\
% 3-rd equation
\shoveleft{ A_{PP}\gamma_{P1} \cos 2\alpha_{S1} +A_{PS}  \gamma_{S1} \sin 2\alpha_{S1} +B_{PP}  \gamma_{P2} \cos 2\alpha_{S2} -} \\
\shoveright{- B_{PS}   \gamma_{S2} \sin 2\alpha_{S2} = \gamma_{P1} \cos 2\alpha_{S1},} \\
% 4-th equation
\shoveleft{ -A_{PP}n_1 \gamma_{S1} \sin 2\alpha_{P1} +A_{PS}  \gamma_{S1} \cos 2\alpha_{S1} +B_{PP} n_2 \gamma_{S2} \sin 2\alpha_{P2} +} \\
\shoveright{+ B_{PS} \gamma_{S2} \cos 2\alpha_{S2} = n_1 \gamma_{S1} \sin 2\alpha_{P1}.}\end{array}
\right.
\] 


\noindent\resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{%
$\setlength{\multlinegap}{0pt}
\left\{
\begin{array}{@{}c@{}}
\shoveleft{A_{PP}\sin\alpha_{P1} - A_{PS}\cos\alpha_{S1} +B_{PP} \sin\alpha_{P2} +B_{PS} \cos\alpha_{S2} =} \\ \shoveright{=\sin\alpha_{P1},} \\
% 2-nd equation
\shoveleft{ A_{PP}\cos\alpha_{P1}  +A_{PS} \sin\alpha_{S1} -B_{PP}\cos\alpha_{P2} + B_{PS} \sin\alpha_{S2} = } \\
\shoveright{ =\cos\alpha_{P1},} \\
% 3-rd equation
\shoveleft{ A_{PP}\gamma_{P1} \cos 2\alpha_{S1} +A_{PS}  \gamma_{S1} \sin 2\alpha_{S1} +B_{PP}  \gamma_{P2} \cos 2\alpha_{S2} -} \\
\shoveright{- B_{PS}   \gamma_{S2} \sin 2\alpha_{S2} = \gamma_{P1} \cos 2\alpha_{S1},} \\
% 4-th equation
\shoveleft{ -A_{PP}n_1 \gamma_{S1} \sin 2\alpha_{P1} +A_{PS}  \gamma_{S1} \cos 2\alpha_{S1} +B_{PP} n_2 \gamma_{S2} \sin 2\alpha_{P2} +} \\
\shoveright{+ B_{PS} \gamma_{S2} \cos 2\alpha_{S2} = n_1 \gamma_{S1} \sin 2\alpha_{P1}.}\end{array}
\right.
$} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: maybe some options in the document preamble prevent the space from disappearing? I tried your code, and I see that the letters are increased, the width is ok, but the spacing is still there.

Comment: @Alexandre: Did you try my example. As you can see in the picture I got no space.

Comment: yep, I tried it. That's what I get: http://img542.imageshack.us/img542/2811/70308726.png .

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,tabularx}
\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}
\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}l@{\kern-10pt}X@{}}
$\left\{\rule{0pt}{4\normalbaselineskip}\right.$
&
\begin{multline}
A_{PP}\sin\alpha_{P1} - A_{PS}\cos\alpha_{S1} +B_{PP} \sin\alpha_{P2} 
           +B_{PS} \cos\alpha_{S2} = \sin\alpha_{P1}, \\
% 2-nd equation
\shoveleft A_{PP}\cos\alpha_{P1}  +A_{PS} \sin\alpha_{S1} -B_{PP}\cos\alpha_{P2} 
           + B_{PS} \sin\alpha_{S2} =\cos\alpha_{P1}, \\
% 3-rd equation
\shoveleft A_{PP}\gamma_{P1} \cos 2\alpha_{S1} +A_{PS}  \gamma_{S1} \sin 2\alpha_{S1} +B_{PP}  \gamma_{P2} \cos 2\alpha_{S2} - \\
\shoveright{-B_{PS}   \gamma_{S2} \sin 2\alpha_{S2} = \gamma_{P1} \cos 2\alpha_{S1},} \\
% 4-th equation
\shoveleft -A_{PP}n_1 \gamma_{S1} \sin 2\alpha_{P1} +A_{PS}  \gamma_{S1} \cos 2\alpha_{S1} +B_{PP} n_2 \gamma_{S2} \sin 2\alpha_{P2} + \\
+ B_{PS} \gamma_{S2} \cos 2\alpha_{S2} = n_1 \gamma_{S1} \sin 2\alpha_{P1}.
\end{multline}
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but with my doc properties the alignment is messed with this solution (the equations cross the brace). I finally used the multlined variant proposed. Thanks again for the help

Answer (score 0):

Analyzing the problem carefully, it is a `dcases` environment of multi-line equations, whose second parts should be right justified (or right aligned, or `\shoveright`, or `\MoveEqRight`... you name it).

You need **the nested `multline` environment** `multilined[t]` for each equation, inside an `\aligned` environment, inside a `dcases` environment.

I am against this practice:

> the brace should appear to the left with no indentation

Thus, I haven't included it in my code.

In the following example, Eq. (1) is not aligned while Eq. (2) is.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[nopar]{lipsum} % for dummy text only
\begin{document}

\lipsum[66] 
%%                  FIRST EQ
\begin{equation}
    \begin{dcases}
        \begin{multlined}[t]
            A_{PP}\sin\alpha_{P1} - A_{PS}\cos\alpha_{S1} +B_{PP} \sin\alpha_{P2} +B_{PS} \cos\alpha_{S2} =\\
            =\sin\alpha_{P1},
        \end{multlined}
        \\
        \begin{multlined}[t]
            A_{PP}\cos\alpha_{P1}  +A_{PS} \sin\alpha_{S1} -B_{PP}\cos\alpha_{P2} + B_{PS} \sin\alpha_{S2} = \\
            =\cos\alpha_{P1},
        \end{multlined}
        \\
        \begin{multlined}[t]
            A_{PP}\gamma_{P1} \cos 2\alpha_{S1} +A_{PS}  \gamma_{S1} \sin 2\alpha_{S1} +B_{PP}  \gamma_{P2} \cos 2\alpha_{S2} -\\
            - B_{PS}   \gamma_{S2} \sin 2\alpha_{S2} = \gamma_{P1} \cos 2\alpha_{S1},
        \end{multlined}
        \\
        \begin{multlined}[t]
            -A_{PP}n_1 \gamma_{S1} \sin 2\alpha_{P1} +A_{PS}  \gamma_{S1} \cos 2\alpha_{S1} +B_{PP} n_2 \gamma_{S2} \sin 2\alpha_{P2} + \\
            + B_{PS} \gamma_{S2} \cos 2\alpha_{S2} = n_1 \gamma_{S1} \sin 2\alpha_{P1}.
        \end{multlined}
    \end{dcases}
\end{equation}
\lipsum[66]
%%                  SECOND EQ
\begin{equation}
\begin{dcases}
    \begin{aligned}
        \begin{multlined}[t]
            A_{PP}\sin\alpha_{P1} - A_{PS}\cos\alpha_{S1} +B_{PP} \sin\alpha_{P2} +B_{PS} \cos\alpha_{S2} =\\
            =\sin\alpha_{P1},
        \end{multlined}
        \\
        \begin{multlined}[t]
            A_{PP}\cos\alpha_{P1}  +A_{PS} \sin\alpha_{S1} -B_{PP}\cos\alpha_{P2} + B_{PS} \sin\alpha_{S2} = \\
            =\cos\alpha_{P1},
        \end{multlined}
        \\
        \begin{multlined}[t]
            A_{PP}\gamma_{P1} \cos 2\alpha_{S1} +A_{PS}  \gamma_{S1} \sin 2\alpha_{S1} +B_{PP}  \gamma_{P2} \cos 2\alpha_{S2} -\\
            - B_{PS}   \gamma_{S2} \sin 2\alpha_{S2} = \gamma_{P1} \cos 2\alpha_{S1},
        \end{multlined}
        \\
        \begin{multlined}[t]
            -A_{PP}n_1 \gamma_{S1} \sin 2\alpha_{P1} +A_{PS}  \gamma_{S1} \cos 2\alpha_{S1} +B_{PP} n_2 \gamma_{S2} \sin 2\alpha_{P2} + \\
            + B_{PS} \gamma_{S2} \cos 2\alpha_{S2} = n_1 \gamma_{S1} \sin 2\alpha_{P1}.
        \end{multlined}
    \end{aligned}
\end{dcases}
\end{equation}
\lipsum[66]
\end{document}
```

I came across the solution after two hours of playing around with `align`, `gather`, `multline`, `split`, `alignat`, `flalign` and all its variants; just before I was about to contact Lars Mad­sen (main­tainer of the `mathtools` package) for an upgrade. It had to be something with an automated format, *in pure LaTeX style*, not through the use of `\quad` or `\hspace` or `\vphantom` or the like.

It is amazing how such a basic typesetting feature is so unknown. I mean, I couldn't find a solution on the whole Internet. It ought to be included in the the guides and tutorials. Multi-line equations are so common!

I knew there had to be more people demanding a solution to this, which I'm now sharing throughout the forum. It also proves how robust the coding of the `mathtools` package is, responding successfully to this workaround.