# \hfill in math mode

Tags: math-mode, horizontal-alignment

Is there any easy way of declaring a new command which emulates `\hfill` in math mode. I don't want `flalign` or something similar. I want to use the command in the same way (and with the same freedom) I use `\hfill`.

Is that possible?

i.e. this is an example:

```
\begin{align*}
    a + b + c &= a + b + c + d + e + f + g + h + i \\
    & \mathhfill \text{(foo)} 
\end{align*}
```

where I want `(foo)` to be right aligned (under `+ h + i` and here

```
\begin{align*}
    a + b + c + d + e + f + g + h + i &= a + b + c \\
    \text{(foo)} \mathhfill &
\end{align*}
```

I want the text aligned on the left (just under the `a + b +`. But I don't want `flalign` or other solutions. Because there are lots of situations (this is a minimal example). And I would like to see a solution which work just as `\hfill`.

**EDIT:** well, as Carlisle said, it works in `$a \hfill b$`, but I would like to see it working in `align`, i.e.

**EDIT2:** The answers solved my needs. But it would be great if somebody would give a command which works exactly like `\hfill` or i.e. `\dotfill` in `align`.

Comment: Is it possible that you are trying to tag the equation and the tag doesn't fit on one line so you are doing it manually?

Comment: No, I'm not tagging. It's just some text which I would like to watch right aligned (and other situations, but at this moment it's just this). But everything would be more flexible if `\hfill` worked.

Comment: Based on personal experience with this kind of situation, I believe this may be a [XY Problem](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2449).  When I started using LaTeX last year, I spent quite a bit of time with exactly the same issue with `align` -- only later did I learn that I did not properly understand how to _fully_ use `align` and the related `alignat` (and even `tabular`/`array`).  So, if you show (in perhaps a different question) exactly what you want to achieve (as opposed to how you want to achieve it) you may get better answers.  If I am mistaken, please ignore this comment.

Comment: No, you are right. And I haven't write a good explanation because I don't have it. I just needed that at this moment (and may be won't need it again, that's why my intention is not to solve my problem, but discovering `\mathhfill`). But I thought *What if we could simply, without head ache, use `hfill`,`dotfill`, etc. in `align` exactly as we use in text mode?* At this moment the @egreg answer fits me, but my real objective is to have a command `\mathhfill` and `\mathdotfill` which work exactly like the normal ones, but **in** `align`.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You can do it, but not with `\hfill`, because of how `align` works. Here's a way:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\pushright}[1]{\ifmeasuring@#1\else\omit\hfill$\displaystyle#1$\fi\ignorespaces}
\newcommand{\pushleft}[1]{\ifmeasuring@#1\else\omit$\displaystyle#1$\hfill\fi\ignorespaces}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
    a + b + c &= a + b + c + d + e + f + g + h + i \\
    & \pushright{\text{(foo)}}
\end{align*}


\begin{align*}
    a + b + c + d + e + f + g + h + i &= a + b + c \\
    \pushleft{\text{(foo)}} &
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

A slightly different implementation allows you to use `\hfill` where you want:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\specialcell}[1]{\ifmeasuring@#1\else\omit$\displaystyle#1$\ignorespaces\fi}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
    a + b + c &= a + b + c + d + e + f + g + h + i \\
    & \specialcell{\hfill\text{(foo)}}
\end{align*}


\begin{align*}
    a + b + c + d + e + f + g + h + i &= a + b + c \\
    \specialcell{\text{(foo)}\hfill} \\
    \specialcell{\hfill\text{(foo)}\hfill}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

I'd recommend *against* using the simple `\omit`.

[image]

Comment: Cool. Well, that works, but I will wait some time just to see if anybody shows a command *more like* `\hfill`. i.e. if you write `(foo1) \mathhfill (foo2)` it will align `(foo1)` to the left and `(foo2)` to the right. If not, I'll accept your answer. May be you could *addapt* `\dotfill` to work in `align`, and then use `\phantom{\dotfill}`

Comment: Great!. That's much better.

Comment: Does this work in `align` environment instead of `align*`? In `align` the compilation fails with `Misplaced \omit`.

Comment: @devil If I run both examples with `align` instead of `align*` I get no error.

Comment: Funny, this seems a bit like re-inventing the wheel for the aligned environment. Indeed, the commands `shoveleft` and `shoveright` basically do the same in the `multlined` environment. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/58529/how-to-align-a-system-of-multiline-equations

That being said, it works great.

Comment: Maybe something has changed in the many years since this answer was made, but I'm getting a "Misplaced \omit" in both align and align* environments.

Comment: @GlenWheeler I get no error at all on a fully updated TeX Live 2023

Answer (score 22):

In align you can use `\omit` at the start of cells:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
    a + b + c &= a + b + c + d + e + f + g + h + i \\        
              &\omit\hfill foo\\        
             a&=b\\        
   \omit text & =c \\
   \omit\hfill text&=d
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: That's also great. But it don't work in every case: i.e. `(foo1) \omit\hfill (foo2)`. Anyway, where can I find info about the `\omit` command?

Comment: The `\omit` must be at the begin of the cell (it tells the underlying `\halign` that in this cell the template should be ignored and is described e.g. in the texbook). Btw: Enrico's solution uses `\omit` too, it is only a bit more hidden.

Comment: Note that it's only the `\omit` that has to be first, the `hfill` can be anywhere ` &\omit$  a \hfill b$` for example

Comment: @David Carlisle and egreg Okey. I'm pleased enough. I like this mode of working. I thank you all, because the solution is a mix of all the answer.

Comment: Note that to be really safe you should only do the omit on aligns second pass not on its first so have a macro \@ifmeasuring\else\omit\fi as in @egreg's solution otherwise you omit this cell on the internal measuring phase (which is safe enough unless the cell ends up being the widest in this column in which case that will not be recorded if you omit it)

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Of course one must be aware of the fact that a cell starting with `\omit` will not apply math mode, nor strip spaces at its end (try `foo \\` in the second row).

Comment: With this solution, it is possible to have part of the second column aligned to the left and another one to the right, for example. I was trying to reach this behavior but I couldn't get it.

Answer (score 6):

The most obvious answer is `\hfill` as demonstrated by this plain TeX file

```
$a\hfill b$

\bye
```

[image]

Comment: Well, I didn't tried that, and it works in `$$`, but this is not what I want. I would like this to work in `align`, `gather` and similar environments.

Answer (score 6):

Another way (the only one that worked for me) is to use `\hskip`. You will have to adjust it manually, though.

```
\begin{align}
     & x + y, &  \text{(Foo)} \hskip0.7\textwidth 
\end{align}
```

Comment: Why not `\hspace` or `\hspace*`?

Comment: works fine as well. Syntax: `hspace{X pt/em/cm}` . But it just gives you the same result -- you have to adjust it manually to get the `\hfill` effect.

Answer (score 4):

I couldn't for the life of me get [@egreg's solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/83522/181375) to work for me: always got `misplaced \omit`, no matter [what I tried](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/426784/181375).  I ended up finding a little bit of a hacky solution, but it works for me.  It uses some code found [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/17808/181375).  Here's the MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\newcommand{\currentsidemargin}{%
  \ifodd\value{page}%
    \oddsidemargin%
  \else%
    \evensidemargin%
  \fi%
}

\newlength{\whatsleft}

\newcommand{\measureremainder}[1]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
    % Helper nodes
    \path (current page.north west) ++(\hoffset, -\voffset)
        node[anchor=north west, shape=rectangle, inner sep=0, minimum width=\paperwidth, minimum height=\paperheight]
        (pagearea) {};


    \path (pagearea.north west) ++(1in+\currentsidemargin,-1in-\topmargin-\headheight-\headsep)
        node[anchor=north west, shape=rectangle, inner sep=0, minimum width=\textwidth, minimum height=\textheight]
        (textarea) {};

    % Measure distance to right text border
    \path let \p0 = (0,0), \p1 = (textarea.east) in
        [/utils/exec={\pgfmathsetlength#1{\x1-\x0}\global#1=#1}];

\end{tikzpicture}%
}

\newcommand\rightalignedtext[1]{\measureremainder{\whatsleft}\begin{minipage}[t]{\whatsleft}\hfill#1\hspace*{1em}\end{minipage}}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
    \begin{aligned}
        a + b + c &= a + b + c + d + e + f + g + h + i \rightalignedtext{(foo)}
    \end{aligned}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for that! I couldn't get egreg's solution to work either.