# `\hfill`-like spacing in math mode without using `align`

Tags: math-mode, spacing, horizontal-alignment, equations

In [question 83509](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/83509/hfill-in-math-mode), a way of getting `\hfill`-like behaviour in the `align` environment is described, but for my purposes, I need one that works in the `equation` environment. (I want to display some commutative diagrams next to each other, but for some reason, `tikzcd` does not like being inside `align`.)

1. Why does TeX ignore `\hfill` inside displayed mathematics?
2. How can this be worked around?

I suppose I could in principle just put the various blocks inside `$...$`, but for consistency, it would be probably be better to have all displayed mathematics in `equation` or similar environments.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can force things to stretch by giving them a large natural width and allowing them to shrink, rather than `\hfill` which has a natural width of 0pt.

so

```
$$a\hskip \textwidth minus \textwidth b$$
```

produces

[image]

But a CD package is almost certainly making a box anyway so placing them inside a display math environment probably doesn't achieve much, however if you mean what I think you mean then putting shrinkable glue between two boxes will force them apart as shown here.

Comment: The `tikzpicture` environment (and by extension `tikzcd`) is, for some strange reason, typeset inline. I always enclose it in `\[ ... \]` to make sure it is displayed like other bits of maths.

Comment: Your solution seems to meet the requirements, thanks! But I'm all the more puzzled: isn't `\hfill` also internally implemented as a kind of `\hskip`?

Comment: @ZhenLin `\hfill` is `\hskip 0pt plus 1fill` so it has a natural width of 0pt and just stretches if needed. the skip I used has a natural size of `\textwidth` and shrinks if needed. When setting a display math TeX is centering it internally so almost never needs to stretch glue so \hfill doesn't stretch,but it needs to shrink this glue so it shrinks by the minimum amount required to make the whole display fit so forces the items apart as far as possible.

Comment: @ZhenLin It's not strange, since one might be producing a very small image to appear inline.  For example, as a special symbol.  More abstractly, it keeps your options open, whereas there is no way to un-display something.