# Is there a way to \mskip 0mu plus 1 fill

Tags: math-mode

I would often like to use a `\hfil` equivalent inside a normal display math without using some `align` like environment or leaving math mode. Is this possible and if yes how? Is this the wrong approach? If yes is there a better one?

The Texbook and TexByTopic are silent on the issue other than that all lengths used by `mskip` have to be in terms of mu which i guess fill can't be expressed in.

Comment: can you describe a particular situation in which you'd like to use this?  you can, of course, try `\mskip 0mu plus 10000mu`, which should be enough to overpower any "ordinary" page width.

Comment: @barbarabeeton I don't know if that's a totally fair alternative.  The analogous technique in horizontal mode was edited out of TeX in 1982!

Comment: Can you please show an example where you would use this infinite `\mskip`?

Comment: @barbarabeeton I think that anywhere where a finite mu stretch has any effect, 1fill would work as intended.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes

```
$a \mskip 0mu plus 1 fill b$
```

Is perfectly legal and produces:

[image]

However your issue is probably that most display environments and the primitive display math suppress stretching as a side effect of boxing and measuring things. For one alternative see an answer from yesterday:

[`\hfill`-like spacing in math mode without using `align`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/111425/hfill-like-spacing-in-math-mode-without-using-align/111426#111426)