# ConTeXt equivalent or succedaneum of multline

Tags: math-mode, context

I want to know if it's possible to define a math alignment so it emulates `multline`. I mean specifically the possibility of having different lines with different alignments each. If my code is the following:

```
\starttext
\startformula
\startmathalignment[n=1,align={middle}]
\NC \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{\sin x}{x}dx=\frac{\pi}{2}\NR 
\NC \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\log\sin xdx=-\frac{\pi}{2}\ln 2\NR
\stopmathalignment
\stopformula
\stoptext
```

all lines will be middle-aligned.
ConTeXt Wiki does not give any clues on how to do something similar. I've tried this: [`\hfill`-like spacing in math mode without using `align`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/111425/hfill-like-spacing-in-math-mode-without-using-align), but this, although compilable, messes up the text presentation.

Comment: There was an answer to this question on the mailing list some time ago, but I have no idea whether this solution still works: https://mailman.ntg.nl/pipermail/ntg-context/2008/030194.html

Comment: It works for me. Thank you very much.