# How to align one equation with another multline equation

Tags: align, multline

I have two equations: The first equation needs to be broken up over two lines (e.g., with multline) so that the rest of the equation is right aligned on the second line.  I would like to have the second equation aligned with the first equation (i.e., their equal signs are aligned), but I can't seem to figure out how to align it *and* have the second part of the first equation be right justified.

Example 1:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}   
\begin{multline}
        \frac{dB}{dt} \approx  - 0.092409  \left(  22.2674  e^{-0.092409 t}+77.7326 e^{-0.0258637 t}  \right)
        \nonumber \\
        -\left( 200 \frac{\ln{\frac{1}{2}}}{26.8} \right) \exp{\left(\dfrac{\ln{\frac{1}{2}}}{26.8}t \right)}
        \nonumber \\
    \approx 2.057708e^{-0.092409 t}+7.18319e^{-0.0258637 t} 
\end{multline}
\end{document}
```

I put everything within `multline` environment, but the 2nd equation is not aligned with the first. 
[image]

---

---

Example 2:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}   
\begin{align}
        \frac{dB}{dt} &\approx  - 0.092409  \left(  22.2674  e^{-0.092409 t}+77.7326 e^{-0.0258637 t}  \right)
        \nonumber \\
        -\left( 200 \frac{\ln{\frac{1}{2}}}{26.8} \right) \exp{\left(\dfrac{\ln{\frac{1}{2}}}{26.8}t \right)}
        \nonumber \\
    &\approx 2.057708e^{-0.092409 t}+7.18319e^{-0.0258637 t} 
        \end{align}
\end{document}
```

Here, I've put everything in an aligned environment. The first equation and second equation are aligned, but the second part of the first equation is left aligned/justified. I would like it right justified and the first and third line left justified/aligned.

[image]

Comment: Are you sure you want the second line right justified?  I did it using a \tag*{$\displaystyle ...$} and it looked awful.  Usualy one \quad past the alignmient point will do.

Comment: @JohnKormylo: In terms of popular practice, what would be the best way to align these equations (assuming a right justified second line isn't aesthetically pleasing?). I just assumed that the second part of an equation should be right justified to distinguish it from a separate equation, but I would be happy to know what the proper convention is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't really answer your question, but might solve your problem.

How about condensing the equation with constants? I threw in a macro `\diff{}{}` for differentials (which should be written with upright d's as it's an operator). Btw, there could be better choices for constants.

[image]

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\diff}[2]{\frac{\mathrm{d}#1}{\mathrm{d}#2}}

\begin{document}   
  \begin{equation}
    \diff{B}{t} = a_1(b_1e^{c_1t}+b_2e^{-c_2t}) - \left(a_2\frac{\ln{\frac{1}{2}}}{b_3} \right) \exp \left(\frac{\ln{\frac{1}{2}}}{b_3}\right)
  \end{equation}
  %
  where the constants $a_i$, $b_i$, and $c_i$ are
  %
  \begin{align*}
    a_1 &= -0.092409, && a_2 = 200,     && \\
    b_1 &= 22.2674,   && b_2 = 77.7326,  && b_3 = 26.8, \\
    c_1 &= -0.092409, && c_2 = -0.0258637, &&
  \end{align*}
  %
  such that
  %
  \begin{equation}
    \diff{B}{t} \approx 2.057708e^{-0.092409 t}+7.18319e^{-0.0258637 t} 
  \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You can also use the `commath` package to get upright d's in math mode with `\dif`

Comment: Although you didn't answer my original question, you provided a better solution to my overall problem.

Answer (score 5):

I think this is what you are trying to achieve, but it doesn't look pretty.

This is based on egreg's solution from [\hfill in math mode](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/83509/hfill-in-math-mode)

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

% from https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/83509/hfill-in-math-mode
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\specialcell}[1]{\ifmeasuring@#1\else\omit$\displaystyle#1$\ignorespaces\fi}
\makeatother

\begin{document}   
\begin{align}
\begin{split}
\frac{dB}{dt} & \approx  - 0.092409  \left(  22.2674  e^{-0.092409 t}+77.7326 e^{-0.0258637 t}  \right)
\nonumber \\
& \specialcell{
\hfill -\left( 200 \frac{\ln{\frac{1}{2}}}{26.8} \right) \exp{\left(\dfrac{\ln{\frac{1}{2}}}{26.8} \right)} 
}
\nonumber \\
& \approx 2.057708e^{-0.092409 t}+7.18319e^{-0.0258637 t} 
\end{split}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

A simple solution with an `aligned` environment inside `align`. I took the liberty to force smaller parentheses on the second line of the split formula.

```
\documentclass[l2pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
  \frac{dB}{dt} & \approx\!\begin{aligned}[t] - 0.092409 \left( 22.2674 e^{-0.092409 t}+77.7326 e^{-0.0258637 t} \right)
  \\[-1ex]
  -\Bigl( 200 \frac{\ln{\frac{1}{2}}}{26.8} \Bigr) \exp{\Bigl(\dfrac{\ln{\frac{1}{2}}}{26.8}t \Bigr)}
  \end{aligned}
  \nonumber \\[1ex]
                & \approx 2.057708e^{-0.092409 t}+7.18319e^{-0.0258637 t}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Use the `multilined[t]` environment from [`mathtools`](https://ctan.org/pkg/mathtools). First, load the package:

> Math­tools pro­vides many use­ful tools for math­e­mat­i­cal type­set­ting. It is based on ams­math and fixes var­i­ous de­fi­cien­cies of ams­math and stan­dard LaTeX.

Analyzing the problem carefully, it is a split environment of aligned equations in which one of the equations is a multi-line equation, for it being too long and whose second part should be right justified (or right aligned, or `\shoveright`, or `\MoveEqRight`...).

You need a **nested `multline` environment** `multilined[t]` inside the `split` environment.

[image]

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document} 
\begin{equation}
    \begin{split}
        \frac{dB}{dt} &\approx
            \begin{multlined}[t]
                - 0.092409  \left(  22.2674  e^{-0.092409 t}+77.7326 e^{-0.0258637 t}  \right)\\
                -\left( 200 \frac{\ln{\frac{1}{2}}}{26.8} \right) \exp{\left(\dfrac{\ln{\frac{1}{2}}}{26.8}t \right)}
            \end{multlined}\\
        &\approx 2.057708e^{-0.092409 t}+7.18319e^{-0.0258637 t} 
    \end{split}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

The solution may seem obvious now, but I came across it after two hours of playing around with `align`, `gather`, `multline`, `split`, `alginat`, `flalign` and all its variants; just before I was about to contact Lars Mad­sen (main­tainer of the `mathtools` package) for an upgrade. It had to be something with an automated format, *in pure LaTeX style*, not through the use of `\quad` or `\hspace` or `\vphantom` or the like.

It is amazing how such a basic typesetting feature is so unknown. I mean, I couldn't find a solution in the whole Internet! It ought to be included in the the guides and tutorials. Multi-line equations are a day to day thing.

I knew there had to be more people demanding a solution to this, which I now share. It also proves how robust the coding of the `mathtools` package is, responding successfully to the workaround.

Enjoy!

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
  \frac{dB}{dt} &\approx  - 0.092409  \left(  22.2674  e^{-0.092409 t}+77.7326 e^{-0.0258637 t}  \right)
        \nonumber \\
    &\phantom{\approx\ }    -\left( 200 \frac{\ln{\frac{1}{2}}}{26.8} \right) \exp{\left(\dfrac{\ln{\frac{1}{2}}}{26.8}t \right)}
        \nonumber \\
    &\approx 2.057708e^{-0.092409 t}+7.18319e^{-0.0258637 t} 
\end{align}
\end{document}
```