# Different alignments with alignat

Tags: align, alignment

```
\begin{equation}\label{eq:f_formulation}
\left\{
\begin{alignedat}{3}
\E(u,z) &= \int_I(u_N,z)_{L^2(\Gamma_N)}+ \int_I(u_V,z)&\\
 &\text{for all } z \in W_{,0D} \text{ with } z(T)=0\\
\tr u &= u_D \text{ on } \Sigma_D &
\end{alignedat}
\right.
\end{equation}

An equivalent variational version is finding $u=u_0 + E u_D$, $u_0 \in W_{,0D}$ with
\begin{equation}
\left \{
\begin{alignedat}{3}\label{eq:f_formulation_variational}
\E(u_0,z) &= -\E(E u_D,z) + \int_I(u_N,z)_{L^2(\Gamma_N)}+ \int_I(u_V,z)&\\
\text{for all } z \in W_{,0D} \text{ with } z(T)=0\\
\tr u_0 &= 0 \text{ on } \Sigma_D &
\end{alignedat}
\right.
\end{equation}
```

Results:

[image]

I want the second equation to look as the first one, in terms of alignement: the second line's end should match up with the first line's end. With the two equals signs still being aligned. Any hint on how to achieve this?

Thanks!

Comment: [This post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/239557/297813) gives a satisfactory, not fully elegant answer.

Comment: The two equals signs you want to align are completely unrelated to one another, so there's no need to align them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can typeset the condition as a zero width box sticking to the left.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\E}{\mathcal{E}}
\DeclareMathOperator{\tr}{tr}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}\label{eq:f_formulation}
\left\{
\begin{alignedat}{2}
\E(u,z) &= \int_I(u_N,z)_{L^2(\Gamma_N)}+ \int_I(u_V,z)&&\\
 &&&\makebox[0pt][r]{for all $z \in W_{,0D}$ with $z(T)=0$}\\
\tr u &= u_D \text{ on } \Sigma_D &
\end{alignedat}
\right.
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

On the other hand, I see no need to look for alignment of unrelated objects.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\E}{\mathcal{E}}
\DeclareMathOperator{\tr}{tr}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}\label{eq:f_formulation}
\left\{
\begin{aligned}
& \E(u,z) = \int_I(u_N,z)_{L^2(\Gamma_N)}+ \int_I(u_V,z) \\
& \qquad\text{for all $z \in W_{,0D}$ with $z(T)=0$} \\[1ex]
& \tr u = u_D \text{ on } \Sigma_D
\end{aligned}
\right.
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Or, if you want that the condition is right-aligned with the top equation,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\E}{\mathcal{E}}
\DeclareMathOperator{\tr}{tr}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}\label{eq:f_formulation}
\left\{
\begin{alignedat}{2}
&\E(u,z) = \int_I(u_N,z)_{L^2(\Gamma_N)}+ \int_I(u_V,z) \\
&&\makebox[0pt][r]{for all $z \in W_{,0D}$ with $z(T)=0$} \\[1ex]
&\tr u = u_D \text{ on } \Sigma_D
\end{alignedat}
\right.
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]