# \hfill in math mode redux

Tags: math-mode, horizontal-alignment

This is a followup to [this thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/83509/hfill-in-math-mode).    I basically followed the construction offered by @egreg.      The following construction throws an error when I have `a & b` in the line with `\pushright`.     If I omit the `b` the code runs.     Is there a way that I can use `\pushright` and have symbols to the right of the `&` sign?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\pushright}[1]{\ifmeasuring@#1\else\omit$\displaystyle#1$\ignorespaces\fi}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{align}
    a  &   b  \pushright{\hfill\text{(foo)}}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

Ultimately, what I want to do is have lines like:

```
\begin{align}
    x_{t+1} = & x_t + f(x_t) - c_t  \pushright{\hfill\text{(eq of motion)}} \\
    x_0     = & \bar{x}       \pushright{\hfill\text{(initial condition)}}
\end{align}
```

and have the phrases `eq of motion` and `initial condition` right aligned just to the left of the equation numbers.       Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like that?

```
\begin{align}
    x_{t+1} = & x_t + f(x_t) - c_t  & \pushright{\hfill\text{(eq of motion)}} \\
    x_0     = & \bar{x}       & \pushright{\hfill\text{(initial condition)}}
\end{align}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

I'm wondering if you are just looking for `\tag`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
    x_{t+1} = & x_t + f(x_t) - c_t  \tag{eq of motion} \\
    x_0     = & \bar{x}       \tag{initial condition}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but I wanted to have the equation numbers as well as the text.

Comment: as for the question and the answer it should be `&=` not `=&`

Answer (score 2):

There is always `flalign`:  If you want the equations centered, replace `\text` with `\llap`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{showframe}

\begin{document}
\begin{flalign}
&& x_{t+1} &= x_t + f(x_t) - c_t  &\text{(eq of motion)} \\
&&    x_0  &= \bar{x}       &\text{(initial condition)}
\end{flalign}
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

Comment: It should be `&=`

Comment: @egreg - What's the point of copying an MWE if we have to fix ALL the mistakes?