# hfill in equation (split, align or subequations, ...)

Tags: equations, alignment, tags

I'd like to have something like this

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[a4paper,top=3cm,bottom=3cm,left=1.5cm,right=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{stix}

\newcommand{\tonde}[1]{\bigl(#1\bigr)}
\newcommand{\Quadre}[1]{\left[#1\right]}
\newcommand{\normadue}[1]{\left\|#1\right\|}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\pushright}[1]{\ifmeasuring@#1\else\omit\hfill$\displaystyle#1$\fi\ignorespaces}
\newcommand{\pushleft}[1]{\ifmeasuring@#1\else\omit$\displaystyle#1$\hfill\fi\ignorespaces}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\Large

\section{Introduction}

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
L\tonde{f\circ\phi}&=\int_I\normadue{\nabla\tonde{f\circ\phi}\tonde{t}}dt=\int_I\normadue{df_{\phi(t)}\Quadre{\nabla\phi\tonde{t}}}dt\\&=\int_I\normadue{\nabla\phi\tonde{t}}dt=L\tonde{\phi}\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\square\notag
\end{split}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

But I used `\qquad` 7 times. Is there I way to simplify my code using a hfill (or other else) such that the `\square` is in the same place of the tag of the equation?
I tried with [this solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/83509/hfill-in-math-mode) but I dislike the result. Could you help me? Thank you so much

[image: notag square]

Comment: You might want to explain what your end goal is without us having to compile the example.

Comment: Why adding meaningless tags?

Comment: @egreg My tag is not meaningless. Its meaning is that this splitted formula is the end of the first part of a proof.

Comment: @Puck I meant the *question tags*.

Comment: Ah, Sorry! I first wrote them in Italian and the translation maybe have changed something... . Thank you for your correction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean something like `\qedhere`?

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[a4paper,top=3cm,bottom=3cm,left=1.5cm,right=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{stix}

%\newcommand{\tonde}[1]{\bigl(#1\bigr)}
%\newcommand{\Quadre}[1]{\left[#1\right]}
%\newcommand{\normadue}[1]{\left\|#1\right\|}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\tonde}{(}{)}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\Quadre}{[}{]}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\normadue}{\|}{\|}


%\makeatletter
%\newcommand{\pushright}[1]{\ifmeasuring@#1\else\omit\hfill$\displaystyle#1$\fi\ignorespaces}
%\newcommand{\pushleft}[1]{\ifmeasuring@#1\else\omit$\displaystyle#1$\hfill\fi\ignorespaces}
%\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}

\begin{proof}[First part of the proof]
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
L\tonde{f\circ\phi}
  &=\int_I\normadue{\nabla\tonde{f\circ\phi}\tonde{t}}\,dt
   =\int_I\normadue{df_{\phi(t)}\Quadre{\nabla\phi\tonde{t}}}dt\\
  &=\int_I\normadue{\nabla\phi\tonde{t}}dt=L\tonde{\phi}\qedhere
\end{split}
\end{equation*}
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

[image]

You get the same output with

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[a4paper,top=3cm,bottom=3cm,left=1.5cm,right=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{stix}

%\newcommand{\tonde}[1]{\bigl(#1\bigr)}
%\newcommand{\Quadre}[1]{\left[#1\right]}
%\newcommand{\normadue}[1]{\left\|#1\right\|}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\tonde}{(}{)}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\Quadre}{[}{]}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\normadue}{\|}{\|}


%\makeatletter
%\newcommand{\pushright}[1]{\ifmeasuring@#1\else\omit\hfill$\displaystyle#1$\fi\ignorespaces}
%\newcommand{\pushleft}[1]{\ifmeasuring@#1\else\omit$\displaystyle#1$\hfill\fi\ignorespaces}
%\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}

\begin{align*}
L\tonde{f\circ\phi}
  &=\int_I\normadue{\nabla\tonde{f\circ\phi}\tonde{t}}\,dt
   =\int_I\normadue{df_{\phi(t)}\Quadre{\nabla\phi\tonde{t}}}dt\\
  &=\int_I\normadue{\nabla\phi\tonde{t}}dt=L\tonde{\phi}\tag*{\qedsymbol}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

but I would ask myself what would be the meaning of ending a proof without ever having started it.

I fixed just the first space before “dt”. You want to fix all those you have in your document.

By the way, you can spot the differences between my version of `\normadue` and yours, where the delimiters are far too big.

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately Overleaf gives me 2 errors (I copied both of your solutions), if you want I can load the Overleaf window. And about delimiters, I prefer a lot that they are a little bit bigger, it's just my style choice.

Comment: @Puck Did you add `\usepackage{amsthm}`?

Comment: Ok now it is correct. Thank you so much