# Why is the spacing different after a multiline array environment?

Tags: spacing, arrays

My goal is to get **equal line spacing** between **text** and **array environments**. This mostly works without any modification, except for one case:
If the array environment consists of **more than one line**, the spacing thereafter is different.
* There is **more space** if another **array environment** follows (cf. column 4), and
* there is slightly **less space** if **text** follows (cf. column 5).

I tried to fix it myself (see \fixSpacingAfterMultilineArray), but this alleviates only the case where an array follows, and worsens the problem whenever text follows.

So my questions are:
* Why is the spacing different after a multiline array environment?
* How can I achieve consistent spacing after the array environment, regardless of the content that follows?

**MWE code:**

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\minip}[1]{%
  \noindent%
  \begin{minipage}[t]{1.3cm}#1\end{minipage}%
}

\newcommand{\arr}[1]{
  \setlength{\arraycolsep}{0pt}%
  \begin{array}[t]{l}#1\end{array}%
  % \par\fixSpacingAfterMultilineArray%
}

\newcommand{\fixSpacingAfterMultilineArray}{%
  % array with two lines has a depth of at least 15.60004pt
  \ifdim\prevdepth>15.6pt%
    \vspace{-1pt}%
  \fi%
}

\begin{document}

\minip{ Col1 TEXT TEXT TEXT}
\minip{ Col2 \arr{ ARR1} \arr{ ARR1} \arr{ ARR1}}
\minip{ Col3 \arr{ ARR1} \arr{ ARR1} TEXT }
\minip{ Col4 \arr{ ARR2 \\ ARR2} \arr{ ARR1}}
\minip{ Col5 \arr{ ARR2 \\ ARR2} TEXT}
\minip{ Col6 TEXT TEXT TEXT}

\end{document}
```

**MWE output:**
[image]

Comment: What you are looking for is \arraystretch.  See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/56101/spaces-between-rows-and-cols-in-a-table-better-ways-than-mine/58135#58135

Comment: @John Kormylo do you mean changing `\arraystretch` at a specific location?

Comment: Note you are missing a `%` after `{` the problem is that the box with the array hides the baseline of the bottom row, l3coffins aim to fix that, meanwhile you can add a `\strut` to the last row so you know that has a known depth then you can adjust the space from a known baseline.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to force `\baselineskip` rather than `\lineskip` to be used by allowing for the depth of the last row (assumed to be that of `\strut`)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}

\newcommand{\minip}[1]{%
  \noindent%
  \begin{minipage}[t]{1.3cm}\raggedright#1\end{minipage}%
}

\newcommand{\arr}[1]{%
  \setlength{\arraycolsep}{0pt}%
  \begin{array}[t]{l}#1\end{array}%
  \par
\vskip-\dp\strutbox
\nointerlineskip\null
}


\begin{document}

\minip{ Col1 TEXT TEXT TEXT}
\minip{ Col2 \arr{ ARR1} \arr{ ARR1} \arr{ ARR1}}
\minip{ Col3 \arr{ ARR1} \arr{ ARR1} TEXT }
\minip{ Col4 \arr{ ARR2 \\ ARR2} \arr{ ARR1}}
\minip{ Col5 \arr{ ARR2 \\ ARR2} TEXT}
\minip{ Col6 TEXT TEXT TEXT}

\end{document}
```